# Запуск проекта под администратором

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Добрый день! как я могу запустить свой проект на другом компьютере в одинаковом со мной домене с моими логином и паролем. Суть проблемы: написал программку которая обрабатывает csv файл в екселевскую табличку. На компьютерах, на которых работают пользователи с админскими правами все работает хорошо, но на компьютере с минимальными правами программа не работает. Обработка идет через npoi библиотеку, и я так понимаю что программе не хватает прав на создание файла и запуск процесса.
через манифест не подходит, т.к. у пользователя в теории нет пароля от админской учетки.

Listing:
https://gist.github.com/Rdk174/a9effd701735867d543379584e86a008

Comment: Использовать службу windows.

Comment: еще один вариант, вероятно ваша программа пытается читать или писать файлы в защищенные от простых пользователей папки. А должна все это делать в персональной папке пользователя. Это первое о чем обычно забывают при разработке

Comment: если просто запустить, то можно батник написать для запуска от нужного пользователя

Comment: @Qwerity: а можно пример?

Comment: @rdorn: программа пишет файлы в директорию программы, а ее пробовал скопировать и на рабочий стол и в документы пользователя.

Comment: Допишите в вопрос условия работы программы. Откуда берется исходный файл - пользователь создает/копирует/скачивает или еще откуда-то? Программа работает постоянно, или по запросу пользователя?

Comment: @rdorn добавил ссылку на гитхаб

Comment: А не пробовали разобраться, зачем вашей программе админские права? Они точно не npoi нужны

Comment: Если вашей программе нужны админские права — это у вас где-то баг. Найдите, для чего конкретно он нужен (то есть, где вываливается без админских прав) и исправьте.

Comment: Да, а в директорию программы писать **нельзя**. Писать можно лишь в `%TEMP%`, в `%APPDATA%\ИмяВашейПрограммы`, и в каталог, который указал пользователь.

Comment: Если на GitHub весь код, то скорее всего, вам нужно задать начальный каталог для FileOpenDialog, честно говоря я не помню куда он по умолчанию смотрит. Выставьте ему по умолчанию папку документов пользователя или профиль пользователя %USERPROFILE% а дальше как указал VladD, с отладчиком по коду в поисках места , где требуются права. Можно для этого отдельного пользователя на своей машине завести

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1 нашел комментарий про дефолтные пути в документации.

Comment: Всем спасибо! буду разбираться

Answer (score -1):

создаем bat файл, в котором пишем:

```
runas /user:domain\admin /savecred c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Вместо admin - имя администратора на компьютере.

Вместо `c:\windows\notepad.exe` - путь до нужной программы.

При первом запуске спросится имя и пароль указанной учетной записи. Вводим, запускается программа. В следующий раз имя и пароль уже не спрашиваются (сохраняются из-за параметра `savecred`).